# What is the right way to say an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

In my school, we had an interesting discussion about how to say an algorithm, because most of the time, we just say, 2 * 2 = 4, 8 * 2 is 16 and then we say the answer is 164. But I was informed that you should say something about 10 of these are one of those ( as in 10 ones is 1 ten ), and we had to state the place value of the number. So what is actually the proper, or most formal, way you could verbally say or right out an algorithm.

Comment: ["Six sevens are forty-two" or "six times seven equals forty-two"](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/20665/372)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess it correctly, you are trying to understand more properly about what the multiplication (algorithm) is doing:
\begin{matrix}
  & 8 & 2 \\
\times &   & 2 \\
\hline
  &  &  \\
\end{matrix}

---

Don't worry if you don't understand everything. I only truly understand after I started learning equations.

As you probably already know, we can break it down into two parts.

Part 1:
\begin{matrix}
  &  & 2 \\
\times &   & 2 \\
\hline
  &  & 4 \\
\end{matrix}

In part 1, we only consider the units digit of the upper number, which is $2$, and use fact that $2 \times 2 = 4$

---

Part 2:
\begin{matrix}
  & 8 &  \\
\times &   & 2 \\
\hline
 1 & 6 &  \\
\end{matrix}

In part 2, we only consider the tens digit of the upper number, which is $8$, and use fact that $8 \times 2 = 16$, or is it really? :)

---

In part 1, there is nothing wrong with our justification, because we are looking at the **units** digit of the upper number, the digit $2$. Since the digit $2$ is the **units** digit, it means the number $2$. So indeed we have $2 \times 2 = 4$.

However, in part 2, something more is going on. We are looking at the **tens** digit of the upper number, the digit $8$. Since the digit $8$ is the **tens** digit, it means the number $80$, not the number $8$. So we actually have $80 \times 2 = 160$

---

In my opinions, this is very confusing for beginners. I myself never understood until I started learning equations.

To make it easier for beginners, there is a simple rule: "blank means nothing and nothing means $0$"

Applying this rule to part 2:
\begin{matrix}
  & 8 &  \\
\times &   & 2 \\
\hline
 1 & 6 &  \\
\end{matrix}

We get:
\begin{matrix}
  & 8 & 0 \\
\times & & 2 \\
\hline
 1 & 6 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}

It works!

---

The final step is to add the first two steps. So because:
\begin{matrix}
  &  & 2 \\
\times &   & 2 \\
\hline
  &  & 4 \\
\end{matrix}

and

\begin{matrix}
  & 8 & 0 \\
\times & & 2 \\
\hline
 1 & 6 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}

We can add $4$ and $160$ to get $164$:
\begin{matrix}
  & 8 & 2 \\
\times & & 2 \\
\hline
 1 & 6 & 4 \\
\end{matrix}

---

So verbally, we can say "Firstly, two times two is four. Secondly, eighty times two is one-hundred-and-sixty. Therefore, we can add four and one-hundred-and-sixty to conclude that eighty-two times two is one-hundred-and-sixty-four."